# Nodejs: Streaming images to a separate server without saving

Tags: node.js, express, streaming

I've been looking for a decent example to answer my question but, not sure if its possible at this point.

**I'm curious if its possible to upload a image or any file and stream it so separate server?** In my case I would like to stream it to imgur.

I ask this because I don't want to reduce the bandwidth hit for all the files to come to the actual nodejs server and upload it from there. Again, I'm not sure if this is possible or if I'm reaching but, some insight or an example would help a lot.

Took a look at Binary.js which may do what I'm looking for but, its IE10+ so no dice with that...

**EDIT: based on comment on being vague**

When the file is uploaded to the node server, it takes a bandwidth hit. When node takes the file and upload it to the remote server, it takes another hit. (if I'm not mistaken) I want to know it its possible to pipe it to the remote service(imgur in this case) and just used the node server as a liaison. Again, I'm not sure if this is possible which is why I'm attempting to articulate the question. I'm attempting to reduce the amount of bandwidth and storage space used.

Comment: Your question is rather vague but I can tell you this: if your node.js app runs on a server and you want to pass some data through your app to another server, it will use your bandwith. The only way to not use your bandwith is to not transmit any data through your app.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. When the file is uploaded to the node server, it takes a bandwidth hit. When node takes the file and upload it to the remote server, it takes another hit. (if I'm not mistaken) I want to know it its possible to pipe it to the remote server and just used the node server as a liaison. Again, I'm not sure if this is possible which is why I'm attempting to articulate the question.

Comment: @delboud Yes, this is possible, and no, it won't save you any bandwidth.  Why do you think bandwidth savings depend on whether or not you put the file on local disk?  No matter what, you're transferring that data from the client, to your server, and then from your server and to Imgur.  You will use the bandwidth in any case.  What you want to do is go directly from the client to Imgur.  I don't know what APIs they have available, but if they allow it, this is possible.  And, it would have nothing to do with Node.js since Node.js runs server-side.